# Xcode 7.1 iOS 9.1 CLLocationManager not always working?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, cllocationmanager

When implementing a CLLocationManager I came across a problem. Sometimes, when launching the app in the iPhone Simulator, it just doesn't fetch the current locations. But when I restart the app or it then suddenly works after 1-3 restarts. Restarting Xcode works too... Here's my code:

```
private var lat = 0.0;
private var long = 0.0;

private var didFindLocation = false

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if (status == .AuthorizedAlways) || (status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        didFindLocation = false
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
    self.lat = location.coordinate.latitude
    self.long = location.coordinate.longitude

    if !didFindLocation {
        print("\(self.lat) - \(self.long)")
        didFindLocation = true
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've created a bool `didFindLocation` that allows me to fetch the location only once. I've put some breakpoints to see what's going on, and when the location doesn't get fetched, `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` doesn't even get called.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have this problem on a device to?

Comment: it happens in simulator .Try to run in device then i hope it will work fine.

Comment: Oh, I've haven't tried it on a device yet. Thanks for the answers! @RashwanL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Simulator do not contains sensors like accelerometer, gyrometer etc, so we should not expect to work them on simulators. Besides this, for fetching a location, perhaps, it is using your system's internet.

So for a fair result it is advisable to use a real device for such cases.

From coding perspective, you can check for `locationServicesEnabled` property of [CCLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/) to see if this service is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen on a simulator, but do add this method so that you get an error message of why it´s not working even though it´s on a simulator

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you check location in simulator then first you need to point your simulator at some location. 
**Why?**

Because simulator is not real time device first you need to point it at some position or location.

**How you can do it?**

There are two ways to do it.

1) select the simulator -> Goto debug -> select location -> select apple location.

Your location method called

> Noto : if you select **custom location** from menu and enter your custom location then you need to restart your simulator (some time multiple times)

[image]

2) Goto xcode -> run your project -> in debug panel you find one location icon -> click on it -> it display location name -> select any place name

> Note : Not necessary it worked all the times.

[image]